# Creating instance of child class from parent class based on some input

Tags: java, oop

There are many answers to this question here on SO, but I wish to add a small bit of twist in my question. Consider a parent class `Parent` and it's children `Child1` and `Child2`. Now, let their structure be something like below:

```
public abstract class Parent {
    public abstract String eat();
    public abstract String sleep();

    public static Parent createInstance (int childType) {
       if (childType == 1) 
         return new Child1();
       else
         return new Child2();
    }
}
```

```
public class Child1 extends Parent {
    public String eat() {
        return "nom-nom";
    }

    public String sleep() {
        return "zzzz...";
    }
}
```

```
public class Child2 extends Parent {
    public String eat() {
        return "gulp-gulp";
    }

    public String sleep() {
        return "ZzZz...";
    }
}
```

Now, my questions are:

- Am I doing something wrong from pure OOP standpoint, by calling the child classes from the parent class?
- Can the above approach be called as an example for strategy design pattern, if I use it in the following way?

```
// In some random class:

public String showMeHowYouEat (int childType) {
    Parent foo = Parent.createInstance(childType);
    return foo.eat();
}

public String showMeHowYouSleep (int childType) {
    Parent foo = Parent.createInstance(childType);
    return foo.sleep();
}
```

Note : I've selected the above approach of creating child class instances from parent class is because I do not wish to write `if-else` every time I have to invoke the `eat` or `sleep` methods based on the `childType`.

My main intention behind asking this question was to simply understand if I'm breaking some rules of OOP paradigm by creating an instance of child from the parent class based on some input. And if I'm doing so, then what could be a better alternative to the above mentioned approach?

Comment: My question is what advantage you are trying to gain with the `Parent.createInstance` in the first place? Why would `Parent foo = Parent.createInstance(1);` be better than `Parent foo = new Child1();`?

Comment: To make it dynamic. I wish to create a child depending upon the `childType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely breaking [SRP rule](http://pragmaticcraftsman.com/2006/07/single-responsibility-principle/)

> A class should have only one reason to change.

Your `Parent` class has definitely more reasons to change because you need to modify it when

1. API will change
2. new child implementation will be delivered.

You should extract this part to some `Factory` class/method outside the `Parent` class

The second question about [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) cannot be answered because you are not showing the context in which you are using

```
int childType = 1;
Parent foo = Parent.createInstance(childType);
```

Maybe it is part of strategy implementation maybe it's not. It depends on how you are using this in the class containing `random method`

Comment: I think, that's definitely not usage of the strategy pattern as there is no strategy injected; it's just hardcoded if/else, simply a normal function.

Comment: Strategy pattern does not require `injection of strategy` - simple if/else is poor and rough but still valid implementation of Strategy pattern

Comment: Sorry for the poor use case example. I've updated my example. Apart from that, as far the `Parent` class is considered, the only change that it will face is the addition of abstract methods and nothing more. Doing things in the above manner saves me the effort of writing `if-else` check of the childType in >1 place.

Comment: I strongly disagree with "Strategy pattern does not require injection of strategy - simple if/else is poor and rough but still valid implementation of Strategy pattern".

Comment: Definition of Strategy pattern is clear and I'm not really sure how you can disagree. Anyway if I'm not right I will be thankful if you will briefly describe why Strategy pattern does not allow you 'simple if/else implementation'

Comment: I agree with @m.antkowicz since, [this](http://w3sdesign.com/?gr=b09&ugr=proble) article says, `switch` can be used to switch in b/w. algorithms. If `switch` is acceptable, then for a binary scenario I think `if-else` should be acceptable too.

Comment: @Argon first of all such rules as SOLID are existing to help us and if it does not help you I really don't think you should stick to them :) Due to the SRP definition - **if** you will add new child implementation you will need to modify parent class; it does mean that there is more than one reason to change this class what is violating SRP. About strategy - your update still does not help with answering is this Strategy or not because this pattern is about how you will **use** such methods not **implement** them :)

Comment: I mean, if we call this a usage of the Strategy pattern just because the argument is used in a condition, then we probably have to call every function with arguments that has ever existed a usage of the Strategy pattern. I prefer to not discuss how exactly this pattern is formally defined but think about it with common sense. If this is the Strategy pattern, then notice that you actually cannot change the algorithm of `createInstance`. It's always the same algorithm, you can't change it at runtime, which is for me the biggest point about the Strategy pattern.

Comment: @m.antkowicz, I'm still not clear how exactly my `Parent` class will change due to delivery of new child implementation. As in, any new child will always follow the signatures of the abstract methods in `Parent`. So, I cannot imagine a use case, where I will change the `Parent` just because of some child. It will be the other way round always (in my case).

Comment: @akuzminykh I agree with you but it's completely different case than "simple if else" that I was writing about

Comment: @Argon you will need to change `createInstance` implementation and add next `if` - this is obviously change of `Parent` class